How to determine if a property (int array) meets the filters
The property named 'catalog' is an array of Int4 in postgresSQL.
[1,2,3,5,8]
i want to filter some records that contains '1' or '2',how can i filter it?
The GPT answer :
 <ogc:Filter>
   <ogc:Or>
     <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:Function name="array_contains">
         <ogc:PropertyName>catalog</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
     </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
     <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
       <ogc:Function name="array_contains">
         <ogc:PropertyName>catalog</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
       </ogc:Function>
     </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   </ogc:Or>
 </ogc:Filter>

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

why doesn't it work? Providing the ChatGPT also supplied you with a working array_contains function (and you installed it) that should work just fine

@lan Turton ,GeoServer warning that  'Unable to find function array_contains'，and I have not idea how to installed the function

did you at least write the function? other wise I would try the in function, but I don't know if that works on arrays
